# FastAPI overwrite pydantic model during startup

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

In my FastAPI application, I want to create a dynamic pydantic model which is used as an input argument. If a condition (that can only be checked during startup) is True, I want to overwrite the model.

In the minimum working example, the model `Model` is initialized with the default value `lim = 10`. In the lifespan event, I overwrite `Model` by initializing a new dynamic model with `lim = 100`.

However, in `/docs`, the default model is still used. Is there a way to overwrite the model such that all endpoints that use it are updated? Since I am using the model as an input argument in multiple endpoints, I would prefer not creating all endpoints dynamically in the lifespan event.

**MWE**

```
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from typing import Annotated, Type

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Query
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model

def dynamic_model(lim=10) -> Type[BaseModel]:
    return create_model("DynamicModel", lim=(Annotated[int, Query(ge=1, le=lim)], 1))

Model = dynamic_model()

@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(_app: FastAPI):
    global Model
    something_is_true = True
    if something_is_true:
        Model = dynamic_model(lim=100)  # overwrite model
        
    yield


app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)


@app.get("/")
async def root(model: Annotated[Model, Depends()]):
    # Using the shortcut to be able to call the endpoint with query parameters
    # https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#shortcut
    return model

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run("main:app", reload=True)
```

**Endpoint with default model**
The MWE does not manage to overwrite the model

[image: Root endpoint with default model]

Comment: I think that's because FastAPI generates openapi scheme before it starts app (and run lifespan). I think you can use approach, that described in this chapter of documentation, to modify openapi scheme https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/how-to/extending-openapi/

Comment: Any reason why it needs to be in a lifespan event, instead of setting up the value before you create app? That way you can import `Model` and use it in your controller endpoints, instead of trying to switch it out inside a lifespan callback.

Comment: @MatsLindh That is actually something I didn't think of yet. As I have to perform additional checks in the lifespan event, I also created the "is_something_true" variable there. Moving everything out and creating `Model` before creating the app solved it. Thanks!